# How to set date for a specific program?

Tags: windows-7, date

after june 2008 the game `gears of war` is giving error and not running.
so when I want to play it, I need to change date about 6 years.
so I'm curious is there anyway to set the time for a single program or change date easier(one click)?

Comment: There is a patch for Gears of War that you have to download. Look for "gears of war windows patch certificate" on google. I can't give you the proper link because I can't search for it here (firewall issues). You can look up the problem you have on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gears_of_War#Digital_certificate_issue)

Comment: To expand what private_meta said, the official page is dead now but the download links are still working. Here's an archived version of the actual page: http://web.archive.org/web/20110528061546/http://gearsofwar.xbox.com/pc/qfe1.htm

Comment: @and31415 the update is not working because I'm using an edited startup.exe to fix little other problems and can't find original startup in internet or anywhere else.

Comment: @mpower As a workaround you might try [RunAsDate](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html).

Comment: @and31415 it didn't work.not changing time soon enough.

Comment: [Related question for Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85336/temporarily-change-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!
I just created a .bat file with these contents:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 skip=1 delims=(-)" %%G IN ('echo.^|date') DO (
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN ('date /t') DO (
    SET v_first=%%G
    SET v_second=%%H
    SET v_third=%%I
    SET v_all=%%A
    )
)

SET %v_first%=%v_all:~0,2%
SET %v_second%=%v_all:~3,2%
SET %v_third%=%v_all:~6,4%
SET DATE2= %MM%/%DD%/%YY%

date 06/01/2008
start /wait "test" "C:\Program Files\Gears of War\Binaries\Startup.exe"
date %DATE2%
```

now you can use it as a oneclick date change program(instead of game shortcut)
it sets date to 2008 and waits for game to end then sets date to now.

Comment: Won't this fail if you play past midnight? :-)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I will fix it when I learn that ... language :-)

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the application *Gears of War* uses Windows' API to determine current date/time.

This means, that *Windows does not set date for each and every application*; instead the application use the current date provided by the OS.

So, you have to change date every time.